# Работа с функцией onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script

работаю с функцией, которая скрывает строки, если они имеют серый цвет, работал по старинке через триггеры, что не всегда удобно. Захотел добавить выполнение через onEdit, но видимо плохо разбираюсь и при вызове функции по новому, ничего не работает. Пробовал по-разному редактировать через мануалы, но не хватает опыта, и не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить функцию, чтобы она исполнялась при редактировании.

```html
function HideRowsByColor() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Заезд/Бронь");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var array = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow).getBackgrounds();

for (i=0 ;i <= lastRow;i++){
if(array[i]== "#999999"){
sheet.hideRows(i+1);

}
  }
}
```

Спасибо большое за внимание.

Comment: Назовите функцию onEdit()

Comment: Спасибо большое, видимо где-то опечатался и не срабатывало ранее. Спасибо!